# Can't fix: 'og:image' error from Sharing Debugger

Tags: html, facebook, og-meta

I want share buttons on my webpage, using og meta tags. But Facebook doesn't use any of my og meta tags. So I tried the debugger, which fetched the latest version. But I can't see what's wrong.

these are my tags

```
<!--FACEBOOK-->
<meta property="og:title" content="Vriendinnendag, het gezelligste dagje Sauna"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="A-Style beautyfarm, Nieuwegein"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="https://astyle.home.xs4all.nl/beautyfarm/index.html"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Dagje BEAUTYFARM met je vriendin? A-Style Spa - Nieuwegein (Utrecht) De gezelligste verwendag. De vriendinnendag is een all-in beautyarrangement voor lage prijs. Top Dagje sauna doe je bij A-Style in Nieuwegein"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://astyle.home.xs4all.nl/beautyfarm/images/Ingang-A-Style-beautyfarm-sneeuw.jpg"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="166407543414563" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="nl-NL" />
```

[this](https://astyle.home.xs4all.nl/beautyfarm/spa_wellness_arrangementen/spa-dag-test.html) is the page where I test this all right now

and this is my sharebutton

```
<!-- Facebook -->
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://astyle.home.xs4all.nl/beautyfarm/spa_wellness_arrangementen/vriendinnendag_wellness_arrangement.html" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" />
</a>
```

and this is the warning from the sharing debugger

> Inferred Property The 'og:image' property should be explicitly
>   provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Comment: This is what you send to Facebook when they scrape your page https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fastyle.home.xs4all.nl%2Fbeautyfarm%2Fspa_wellness_arrangementen%2Fvriendinnendag_wellness_arrangement.html

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue.

I had to set og:url "to my main page, and that's the spot where it looks for the 'og' elements. 
og:url should point to a webpage what contain the OG element